# SQL Server Temporal Table - tracking deletion when using service account

Tags: sql-server

I have a generic service account that is used by a web application to call a stored procedure to delete records in a temporal table I have. The stored procedure gets the web user id (which is what I want to track).

For updates and inserts, it's easy - insert/update and make sure the UserId field is populated with the web application's user id.

I'm stuck on deletions - the only mechanism I can think of is to do an update on the UserId field with the web user id and then do a delete. This obviously is one more step than I want, but it also yields an additional record in the history table I don't want.

Is there a best practice to solve this?... or do I already have the best available solution here?

Comment: Temporal tables are not audit tables. They can be used as part of auditing, but aren't enough on their own. It sounds like you've got a `UserID` column in a table that logically doesn't need one at all save for recording the user who performed a certain action -- which is properly part of an audit record only.

Comment: I understand that. What I'm looking is for a best practice on how to track user ids for deletions on a temporal table coming in through a service account.

Comment: Just reread your comment - is the implication that the proper way to structure this to begin with is to have a third table to track auditing?